# Python 3 function to convert "&#1044;" to string

Tags: python-3.x, chr

The task is to convert `&#1044;&#1077;` to `Де`.
Does Python 3 has builtin function or I need to parse this string and then use builtin `chr` method to convert each number to string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`html.unescape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.unescape) function:

```
import html

text = '&#1044;&#1077;'
result = html.unescape(text)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works as I expected.

Comment: interesting usage of bold there, it must be a pain to type, though :-)

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard: well after some 100 posts you can do it automatically. Furthermore you can program it into the Advantage Kinesis keyboard :)

Answer (score 2):

In python 3.4 and above, you can use [`html.unescape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.unescape):

```
>>> import html
>>> print(html.unescape('&#1044;&#1077;'));
Де
```